# Reuse promise with arguments

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want to use a promise with arguments, like the following psudo code:

```
let lookForXPromise = new Promise(arg1. arg2, function(resolve, reject){
    asyncFunc(arg1, arg2, function(value){
      if(value != "undefined"){
        resolve(value);
      }
      else{
        reject(); // didn't find X
      }
     });
   });

lookForXPromise(1, "foo").then(
  function(val){ ... do something...
}).catch(){ ...
```

But it appears that a promise only receives `function(resolve, reject)`, so how can I declare a promise and reuse it with different arguments?

EDIT: this is so it will be possible to iterate over a collection of values and each time send different value to the promise.

Comment: You don't reuse promises. You create new ones. What you want is a factory creating promises based on arguments provided to it. So you need a factory function that accepts your arguments around the promise, not inside it

Comment: Oh cool, is there a promise factory that I can use without bringing in angular or another library? @TJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise is *not* a function; it is the "*promised future return value*" of a function. Therefore, you'd just write a function that takes those arguments and creates a new promise:

```
function lookForXPromise(arg1, arg2) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    asyncFunc(arg1, arg2, function(value){
      if(value != "undefined"){
        resolve(value);
      }
      else{
        reject(); // didn't find X
      }
    });
  });
}

// now you can call lookForXPromise as a function:
lookForXPromise(1, "foo")
  .then(() => { /* ... */ })
  .catch(() => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I want to iterate over an array and send different arguments each time...